# Transferring Variables Through a webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to transfer a variable through a web page using asp.net. I know they are ways of doing this by using `Session Variables` but I do not want to use session variables, is there any way to do this without using session variables?

(I'm also programming in vb.net, I don't know if that matters or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways.

You can store it in the view state
You can store it as a querystring to a url
You can store it in a <input type="hidden"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know english very well sorry about this.

You can use viewstate to store your data like session but it requires more attention because of force bandwith. And if you store you data in viewstate, you must serialize object but it don't need for values. See for [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)